# Pruning a Bitcoin full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I am running a full node and considering pruning to gain some disk space.

Does Bitcoin Core know how to prune the existing database or will it start the entire sync process over?

How much free disk space does the process require?

Will the pruned .dat file be deleted by the process?

Answer (score 2):

> Does Bitcoin Core know how to prune the existing database or will it start the entire sync process over?

It knows what to do and you will experience no resync or reindex when you do the pruning process (barring any unclean shutdowns or sudden power loss). There is no noticeable effect when pruning except that the size taken up on disk is much smaller.

> How much free disk space does the process require?

No additional space is required. Disk space will be freed up by pruning, not consumed.

> Will the pruned .dat file be deleted by the process?

Yes, that is how it frees disk space.

Comment: Thanks. I previously maxed out the partition available disk space, possibly 2-3 GB left. After attempting to prune, GUI not launching, I was not able to launch even without pruning settings. The former suggest/s/ed some temporary extra space may be required.

I might have interrupted the pruning process, in which case no progress status would show on 0.13.2?